# How to set variable in the query string parameter type for a REST request in soapUI

Tags: soapui

I am new to soapUI. I want to set a variable from an external source in the query string parameter method for a REST request. Kindly suggest.

I am able to send the request with single values hardcoded but I want to set a variable  in the query string.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a custom property, for example here called `authorisationToken` and defined at the project level, and add that to your resource parameters using the [property syntax](https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/property-expansion.html):

[image]

How you update that property is then up to you. You could edit it manually in the Custom Properties dialog or set it in a Groovy test step using:

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("authorisationToken", "your value")
```